# Loop a where clause?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I specify a where clause:

```
$this->model = $model->where('published', '=', '1');
$this->model->get();
```

The above works fine, giving a query log of:

```
select * from `products` where `published` = ?"
```

But I need to loop through where clauses from an array.

```
$arr = [['published', '=', '1'], ['id', '=', '1']];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $model = $model->where($value);
}
$model->get();
```

But with the above I get a column not found. Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'.

Where am I going wrong?

Further to this, if I just pass in the entire array, it works:

```
$model = $model->where($arr);
```

Giving a query log of:

```
"select * from `products` where (`published` = ? and `id` = ?)"
```

But the where clauses are in brackets... why?

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking that you want to pass whatever values are in the array to your `where`? For example if you had `[['col', '=', 'val']]` it would result in `$model->where('col', '=', 'val')`?

Comment: Yes, thats correct, and I can already do that with $model->where($arr); but the issue with this is that it causes brackets around my where clause. Why does it do this and what do the brackets mean?

Comment: Try removing the assignment so `$model = $model->where(...);` becomes `$model->where(...);`. Does that do anything? You often get brackets around where clauses when you do something like `$model->where(function($query) { // Extra where clauses });`

Comment: I've removed the assignment, still the same issue.

Comment: Try this one:

`foreach ($arr as  $value) {
    $model->where($value[0],$value[1],$value[2]);
}`

It is array of 0,1,2,3..... indexing.

Answer (score 4):

## Solution 1

```
$query = new Model;

foreach($arr as $condition){
   $query->where($condition[0], $condition[1], $condition[2]);
}

$query->get();
```

This will create a query like the following

```
Select * from table where published = 1 and id = 1;
```

Here you can see that the values are not in brackets as they are not a combined result.

## Solution 2

This solution will create a combined for where clauses and the final result will be in brackets

```
$query = new Model;
$query->where(function($q) use ($arr){
    foreach($arr as $condition){
        $q->where($condition[0], $condition[1], $condition[2]);
    }
}

$query->get();
```

This will result in exact query that you have achieved. This is because the solution is breakdown of what is happening inside your query **$this->model->where($arr)**

```
Select * from table where (published = 1 and id = 1);
```

## NOTE

To further know why this happen's look at the following example

```
Select * from table where (id = 2 or product_id = 3) and (publish = 1 and status = 2)
```

With this query you can see that it is a mixture of solution 1 and solution 2. The you solve it is

```
$query = new Model;
$query->where(function($q) use($input) {
    $q->where('id', '=', $input['id1'])
       ->orWhere('id' , '=', $input['id2']);
}
```

Till now we have created the following result

```
Select * from table where (id = 1 or id = 2)
```

Now to add the next part of the query we do the following

```
//continued from above
//$query has the above condition which can be continued after the first where for chaining or in next line.
$query->where(function($q) use($input){
    $q->where('publish' ,'=', 1)->where('status','=',1);
}
```

Now with this, the final query becomes the one we required. Hope now it is  clear why there were brackets added.

Comment: Thanks, just a quick question, what do brackets actually do around parts of the where clause?

Comment: This is just like BODMAS (Brackets then Off then Division then Multiplication then Addition then Subtraction). The content of the brackets will be computed first then resultant will be used for final comparison. 
Breakdown
**Select * from table where (conditions) and (conditions) 
> Select* from table true and true;**

Answer (score 2):

I've just managed to get something working:

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();

$model = (new User)->newQuery();

$wheres = [
    ['forename', '=', 'Joe'],
    ['surname', '=', 'Bloggs'],
    ['email', '=', 'test@test.com']
];

foreach ($wheres as $where) {
    // Call $model->where(...) passing in each array item as a separate param
    call_user_func_array([$model, 'where'], $where);
}

$result = $model->get();

dd(\DB::getQueryLog(), $result);
```

This results in the query:

```
select * from `users` where `forename` = ? and `surname` = ? and `email` = ?
```

The trick seemed to be adding the `->newQuery()` part when creating an instance of the model on which to run the query.

Note, the `call_user_func_array` passing each item of the array to `$model->where(...)`. I found that passing an array to `->where(...)` results in the builder attempting to add several `where` clauses. An added benefit of using `call_user_func_array` is also that it will pass however many parameters you want to provide in each clause - doesn't need to be exactly 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the column name.
Try this:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $model = $model->where($value[0],$value[1],$value[2]);
}
```

Comment: It's not an associative array.

Comment: @panthro sorry didn't notice that. But, since the `$value` itself is an array, will the above update do ?

Comment: What if the array doesnt have 3 values?

Comment: Also does not answer my other question.